# I want to add button on bottom of screen when clicked on extension icon directly with no default popup

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, manifest.json

I want to make an extension in which when clicked on icon it will display a button in current window only at bottom left the problem is i tried using iframe but chrome is blocking it and do not know any other method
Can any one suggest a method to achieve it in chrome extension the language used are html,css,javascript in these

i tried using iframe in content script but it is blocked by google and also tried chatgpt but it also cannot give solution in it